# Inline svg showing black in safari but works perfectly on chrome

Tags: javascript, svg, safari

I am trying to use a inline svg above a canvas element as grid. The problem is that svg grid is showing black in safari while it works fine on chrome. I have tried actual url for fill, tried viewbox but nothing is working. I have tested by using object tag but the problem with that I doesn't catch my right click events which I need above the svg grid. Here is my code

```
   <svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="grid10" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path
        d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10"
        fill="none"
        stroke="gray"
        stroke-width="0.5"
      />
    </pattern>
    <pattern
      id="grid100"
      width="100"
      height="100"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    >
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#grid10)" />
      <path
        d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100"
        fill="none"
        stroke="gray"
        stroke-width="1"
      />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid100)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Does the page contain a <base> tag?

Comment: yes its on Angular 8, and it has base tag, I have tried to remove it but no luck.

Comment: Safari really doesn't like <base> tags. They interfere with its SVG URL resolution.

Comment: I have tried to add full url paths as well but no luck with that also. The same svg is working on Angular JS, but not on angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on our project. Generally it's an issue with url referencing. In Angular 8 it's caused by `<base href="/">`. The simplest solution is to use `<img src="image-path/your-image.svg">` instead of the inline svg. Another possible solution is to read the current url with window href or define it absolutely.